# MySQL Outer Join and similar tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table, say, country_previous and another table country_current. Both are same in structure, only the names are different. See the structure of them below :

```
CREATE TABLE `country_previous` (
`name` varchar(70) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
PRIMARY KEY (`name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 MAX_ROWS=100000000 AVG_ROW_LENGTH=50
```

and the other one

```
CREATE TABLE `country_current` (
`name` varchar(70) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

So as the names indicate, country_previous has all the country names until, say an year ago, and country_current has all the countries until now. So I want to get all the countries that were created after the last update of country_previous. I tried this query,
but it has many entries from country_previous.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM country_previous NATURAL RIGHT OUTER JOIN country_current WHERE   country_previous.name IS NULL;
```

That gives more count than expected. For eg: my country_previous has 90 countries and country_current has 110 countries. Then, I should get only the new countries since then(country_previous's last update), which is 110 - 90 = 20. But I get more than 20.

so what's wrong with the query and what should I do ?

Thanks in advance.

PS : This country idea is just an example that really helps me to make others understand what I really need and I am not doing anything with country names actually.

Comment: You cannot do this with this table structure.

Because names in both tables are different that is USA will not match United States of America and thus no point to join two tables And there is no other column to compare.

Comment: Zohaib, I am sorry that I did not add an important point earlier. I have just updated my post with it. Here is it for you, anyways : PS : This country idea is just an example that really helps me to make others understand what I really need and I am not doing anything with country names actually.

Comment: Also, note that using a name property as a Primary Key / Unique Identifier could be considered dangerous.  If you notice a spelling mistake in the name, and change it, you have also implicitly changed its PK/ID.  Anything referencing that PK/ID will now also need updating.  By having a surrogate key, such as an auto-incrementing id field, changes to the name property now have zero effect on relational integrity.

Comment: @Dems: while I do favor surrogate keys - preferably plain integer serial numbers because integers are small and fast - changes to the `name` would not be a problem if you'd define foreign keys with `ON UPDATE CASCADE`.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter - Not all situations allow CASCADE, such as circular references.  Agreed that it is useful, and may apply here, but it is not a universal fix to such considerations.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using the following query:

```
select count(*) from country_current cc
where cc.name not in (select cp.name from country_previous cp);
```

This will give you a count of all country names in `country_current` that are not in `country_previous` (which I think is what you are after?).

Or, if you fancy using a join to do this then you could use something like the following:

```
insert into country_current values ('USA');
insert into country_current values ('China');
insert into country_current values ('Russia');
insert into country_current values ('UK');
insert into country_current values ('France');

insert into country_previous values ('Russia');
insert into country_previous values ('UK');
insert into country_preivous values ('France');
```

and then run:

```
select sum(case when cp.name is null then 1 else 0 end) as newCountries
from country_current cc
left outer join country_previous cp on cc.name = cp.name;
```

Comment: Yes Tom, I agree. But I would like to know if I can do it with any sort Join conditions.

Comment: OK. I didn't know that you wanted to use a `JOIN`. I've added an example of how I would go about doing the same thing with a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. Hope it is what you're after

Comment: @TomMac - Could replace the `SUM(CASE)` with `COUNT(*)` by adding `WHERE cp.name IS NULL`.  +1 for correct and informative answers.

Comment: Thank you, Tom. Can you please shed some light on why my query fails as well ?

Comment: @Tom - Also, is there a way to move 'is null' in your query (I mean the argument to the sum function) to the end(that is after, on cc.name = cp.name ). Is that possible at all ?

Comment: @user1089770 - ISNULL is only needed if there are 0 records in `country_current`.  In all other cases the CASE statement returns either 1 or 0, and then that is summed to a non-NULL value.

Answer (score 0):

If the country names are similar then minus query is as follows

```
SELECT count(*) from (    
SELECT cc.name from country_current cc
MINUS
SELECT cp.name from country_previous cp)
```

Answer (score 0):

The query returns unexpected results cause there might be some countries in country_previous that doesn't exist in the table country_current. Thus, when you make the verification country_previous.name IS NULL, it doesn't work on these records.